# How to control CallKit Speaker Button in ios 10

Tags: ios, callkit

When I use CallKit in my project, I don't know how to control the speaker button. Other buttons like mute,hang up and so on can be control. When I test my project, I found that the 'AVAudioSession' instance is changed when I tap the speaker button, but the result is unsatisfactory. When I tap once, the speaker button is not changed selected status , sure, speaker is not opened. Twice the speaker button is changed to selected status. But the speaker effect seems to me very strange. I want to know the system mechanism of CallKit framework so that I can modify my code about 'AVAudioSession'. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Speaker has some issues in callkit. To enable speaker, sometimes two times need to tap. I hope, it is the ios bug.

Comment: Whenever the control moves to your app from Callkit, you have to detect programmatically speaker is enabled or not, by checking the audio route/port.

Comment: Yes. I also found that we need to tap two times. I test 'whatsApp' also has this issue.I see what you means.I hope Apple can solve this issue as early as possible. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66308

You will have to listen for audio route changes and perform speaker phone actions when the audio route changes to speaker mode.

Comment: Can you send me any sample how can listen it?